# Selenium browser forgets search preferences

Tags: python, selenium

I am executing a python script to scrape data off the first 5 pages of searching papers on the SSRN database. Currently what I have working right now is

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3//a")
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    extract_information(href,sheet,excel_data_pointer,workbook)
```

This is all currently being done on page 1 of my website. I also have some additional search preferences specified in my code namely:

[image]

Where this is the last option on the search dropdown. I access this on the first page by using:

```
select_element = Select(browser.find_element_by_css_selector('select#sort-by'))
#Modify me to change the Sorting filter
select_element.select_by_visible_text("Date Posted, Descending")
browser.implicitly_wait(2)
```

Then I run the code I stated at the start, extract the links and use a helper function to perform my scraping. My problem begins in the second page. When it loads the browser pauses for a second and switches back to the old search preferences and now it looks like:

[image]

I am using a for loop to traverse through the pages in the script accessing them by:

```
for i in range(2,num_papers):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='maincontent']/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/ul/li["+ str(i) +"]/a").click()
```

My first question would be why does this happen? Does the browser not automatically remember search preferences? I have tried accessing the drop down again on this page but it doesn't seem to change. Is there a way to have selenium browsers memorise these preferences?

EDIT: I was also searching by "Title, Abstract and Keywords" in my original search which worked well on page 1 but by page 2 it started to search through "Title and Abstract" only (the default option)

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I am guessing that each time you go to a new page, that page is newly rendered from the server and thus your search preferences get overriden. I'm not sure if anything can be done from a Selenium or client perspective.

Comment: Hi Vinay, thank you for your response, that's a bit problematic as I require these search preferences to be maintained, are you aware of any alternative approaches?